# Center a UIView without affecting the position of other UI classes in UIKit programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I want to move the position of a UIView `boardGame: UICollectionView` to be on the center of the screen by modifying the constraints properties such as `topAnchor`, but anything I do to it seems to affect the content inside of it. I have also defined a `UICollectionViewCell` model so I can be register the cells in `boardGame` as "uinique".

```
import UIKit

class BoardViewController: UIViewController {

    private let boardGame: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let board = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        board.allowsSelection =  true
        board.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "unique")
        board.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return board
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(boardGame)
        boardGame.backgroundColor = .systemGray2
        
        boardGame.frame = view.bounds
        
        let margin: CGFloat = 20
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               
            boardGame.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: margin),
            boardGame.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                   boardGame.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            
                  
                   boardGame.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -20),
                   boardGame.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -20),
               ])
        
       
        
        boardGame.delegate = self
        boardGame.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    init() {
           super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
       }
       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
}

extension BoardViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 9
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "unique", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

              
              let chessRow = indexPath.row / 3
              if chessRow % 2 == 0 {
                  if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                  }else{
                      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                  }
              } else{
                  if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
                      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                  }else{
                      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                  }
              }
          
              return cell
          }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            // Divide the width by 3 to create a 3x3 grid
            let width = collectionView.frame.size.width / 4.0
            let height = width
            return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }
    
}
```

Here is the `CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell` model:

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   
    let titleLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And the parent view that receives the instance of the `BoardViewController`

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    let boardView = BoardViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        addBoardView()
    }
    
    func addBoardView(){
        addChild(boardView)
        view.addSubview(boardView.view)
        
     
        boardView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

I have tried playing around with the properties of the `constant: CGFloat` in `topAnchor` in `boardGame`. To give some context here is an example of what I get with `boardGame.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20)`,

[image]

If I change the `CGFloat` to 200 to make it more centered the properties of the `CustomCollectionViewCell` inside it moved to the edged afecting the top margin like so:

[image]

I already tried to mess with the `titleLabel` top margin `constraint` inside of `CustomCollectionViewCell` but does not seem to do anything.

How could I keep the `boardGame` view in the center without affecting the margin of `CustomCollectionViewCell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells are positioned at the top edge of the collection view, because *that's how collection views work*. This is by design. The cells only *appear* "centred", when the collection view is at the top of the screen, because the cells are laid out to avoid the safe area (the dynamic island in this case) by default.

In any case, your constraints are contradictory. You are saying that the `boardGame` view should have a fixed width and height (assuming the superview's width and height are fixed), and its centre point should be the same as the superview's centre point (`centerX = view.centerX` and `centerY = view.centerY`), *and* its top is only 20 points away from the superview's top.

These cannot all be satisfied simultaneously. As you can see in the first screenshot, the `centerY = view.centerY` constraint is broken, to satisfy the other constraints.

If you want the collection view to be centred both vertically and horizontally, just remove the top margin constraint:

```
boardGame.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: margin)
```

If you also want the cells to be centred vertically, you can set `contentOffset`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    boardGame.contentOffset.y = (boardGame.contentSize.height - boardGame.bounds.height) / 2
}
```

That said, if `boardGame` is not supposed to be scrollable, consider using a series of `UIStackView`s for this layout instead. Example:

```
class BoardViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var boardGame: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        func makeCell(color: UIColor) -> Cell {
            let cell = Cell(frame: .zero)
            cell.backgroundColor = color
            return cell
        }
        
        func makeColumn(_ views: [UIView]) -> UIStackView {
            let col = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)
            col.axis = .vertical
            col.spacing = 8
            col.alignment = .center
            col.distribution = .fillEqually
            return col
        }
        let col1 = makeColumn([makeCell(color: .black), makeCell(color: .black), makeCell(color: .black)])
        let col2 = makeColumn([makeCell(color: .white), makeCell(color: .white), makeCell(color: .white)])
        let col3 = makeColumn([makeCell(color: .black), makeCell(color: .black), makeCell(color: .black)])
        let columns = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [col1, col2, col3])
        columns.axis = .horizontal
        columns.spacing = 16
        columns.distribution = .fillEqually
        columns.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        boardGame = UIView()
        boardGame.backgroundColor = .gray
        boardGame.addSubview(columns)
        boardGame.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(boardGame)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            columns.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boardGame.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            columns.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boardGame.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            columns.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boardGame.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            columns.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: boardGame.rightAnchor, constant: -8),
            boardGame.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            boardGame.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            
            
            boardGame.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -20),
            boardGame.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -20),
        ])
    }
    
}

class Cell: UIView {
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```